# How to get the call log from my iPhone in iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to get the call log from my iPhone. What is the path to get the call log from iOS 8.3?

Comment: Did you check the user manual? It's trivial to get the log by tapping the phone app. Please do more research and show that research before asking here. We've warned you several times about low quality questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call history is in the database located at:

```
/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db
```

Comment: this works only in iOS 4

Answer (score 0):

The iOS 8 location is `/var/mobile/Library/CallHistoryDB`.

On my phone this directory looks like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mobile mobile 335872 Sep 14 13:29 CallHistory.storedata
-rw-r--r-- 1 mobile mobile  32768 Sep 21 16:27 CallHistory.storedata-shm
-rw-r--r-- 1 mobile mobile 366712 Sep 21 15:29 CallHistory.storedata-wal
-rw-r--r-- 1 mobile mobile  28672 Jun 29 15:59 CallHistoryTemp.storedata
-rw-r--r-- 1 mobile mobile  32768 Sep 21 19:14 CallHistoryTemp.storedata-shm
-rw-r--r-- 1 mobile mobile      0 Jun 29 15:59 CallHistoryTemp.storedata-wal
-rw-r--r-- 1 mobile mobile    296 Sep 21 18:53 com.apple.callhistory.databaseInfo.plist
```