# How to retrieve older (1 week) call on iphone 13 ios 16.3

Tags: iphone, ios, backup

Need to retrieve a call done a week ago (Wed 18th Jan 2000hrs). This was just a dialed number hence isn’t available on carrier billing history.

Whats done so far:

1. Deleted recent (20th to 25th) calls. However, older calls still dont refresh/appear, even when history has only ~10 logs remaining.
2. Tried iMazing. Using both types of backups, it only shows the ~10 that are available on my recents.
3. Touchcopy. From video on their website, it only shows history from calls that appear in recents.
4. Tried backing up and upgrading from ios 16.2 to 16.3
5. Local apple support said logs older than a week are deleted and im on my own. Btw, step 1 was done yesterday 1100hrs still within 1wk i presume, with no result.

Extra info:

- Dialed no was not a saved contact
- Have sufficient storage ~400gb
- If possible,without having to try restoring phone from backup; or proprietary software.

Comment: If the call doesn't show up in iMazing it is most likely not in the log anymore. I assume you looked at the DB listed in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/190227/how-to-get-the-call-log-from-my-iphone-in-ios-8?rq=1 ?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270912/retrieve-older-call-history-on-iphone?rq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/190227/how-to-get-the-call-log-from-my-iphone-in-ios-8?rq=1

Comment: Unless this has changed in iOS 16, the call list is not determined by time, but by number [looks to be about the last 100.] My call log goes back to February 2022. If I delete a few from later in the list, it goes back further.